# I'm having issues with overriding an exception using java

Tags: java

I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, however I want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I tried catching the exception and using the `throws` declaration which doesnt seem to resolve the issue. How can I throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs ?

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: The @throws tag (propably used in the documentation of the method?) Doesn't do anything at runtime. So what about this tutorial? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: No i mean how can i throw an illegalargumentexc INSTEAD OF an illegalargumentexception when an array index is iut of bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `catch` `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and then `throw` `IllegalArgumentException` as shown below:

```
  try {
       //Add your code here

  } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayIndexExe) {
    //Change the below message according your requirement
    String message ="Input Validation failed because of incorrect data"; 

    //You can set the cause (2nd arg) below as ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(message, arrayIndexExe);
  }
```